# How to use date as parameters for a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rake task as below, where one needs to input the date in the `import_date` section in order to execute it. The date put in the `import_date` section then gets saved in a column called `import_date` in a table.

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task: create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
  #actions
```

Now, I want the code to only work if the right kind of date was put in. If the format was wrong, I want it to not execute the rake task, but give me an error code, telling me that the date format is wrong.

```sh
# This should work
RAILS_ENV=production ./bin/rake member:create_csv[20201119]

# This shouldn't work, because the date has too many digits.
RAILS_ENV=production ./bin/rake member:create_csv[20200001119]
```

Would the code below be appropriate in order to do so?

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task: create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
    require 'date'
    date = Date.today
    if args.worked_on == date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
      # action
    else
     p "ERROR"
    end
  end
```

**Update**

I don't necessarily want it the code to compare the 'import_date' to today's date, I want it to just see if the 'import_date' put in by the user follows the rule of "%Y%m%d".
In this case, would the code below be better?

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task: create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
  if args.import_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    # action
  else
    p "ERROR"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_date`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date) method on a string to convert `args` to `Date` object. Then you can call `today?` method to check the passed date. Also, you don't need to require `date` it's already required by Rails.

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task :create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
    if args['import_date'].to_date.today?
      # action
    else
      p "ERROR"
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, if the date format is incorrect you'll get this exception `ArgumentError: invalid date`

**UPD**

If you want to compare with the other date.

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task :create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
    if args['import_date'].to_date == Date.new(2020, 11, 26)
      # action
    else
      p "ERROR"
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to make sure that your argument is following the certain pattern

```
namespace :graduated_member do
  desc 'import member'
  task :create_csv, ['import_date'] => :environment do |task, args|
    Date.strptime(args['import_date'], '%Y%m%d')
      # action
    rescue ArgumentError
      p "ERROR"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! The date doesn't necessarily have to be today's date, I just want it to see if the 'import date' put in by the user follows the pattern of  "%Y%m%d". In this case, how would you change the code?

Comment: Thank you so much for the update!!! You are my hero!!

Comment: You are very welcome. Please mark this answer as the correct one if it is.